# Can't find newly-created folders in file system

Tags: java, authentication, javafx, filesystems

I'm trying to create a folder for save files if it doesn't already exist, but I can't find the folders I'm creating in the filesystem after I run my code.

Here's the event handler for my login button:

```java
@FXML
private void loginBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    // Check for save file folder and create if not exist
    splashMessages.appendText("Checking for save folder... ");
    File saveFolder = new File("../../saved_profiles/");
    if (!saveFolder.exists()) {
        splashMessages.appendText(" not found.\n");

        try {
            saveFolder.mkdir();
            splashMessages.appendText("Folder created in " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\n");
        }
        catch (SecurityException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        splashMessages.appendText(" found.\n");
    }
}
```

If I change `../../saved_profiles/` to something else and click my button, the messages it displays in my textarea suggest that it's created the directory. If I then press the button again, it doesn't try to create another new one, either (i.e. it prints "Checking for save folder... found." to the textarea).

The issue here is that I can't find the folders in my filesystem where it says it's created them. Anybody know where I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be 100% sure, add a debug line showing the full path:

```
File saveFolder = new File("../../saved_profiles/");
if (!saveFolder.exists()) {
  System.out.println(saveFolder.getAbsolutePath());
  ...
```

This will show you the path without any relative segments, so from the root of your filesystem.

Comment: Thanks! I had just thought to go do that, and you saved me the trouble of having to look up the getter to use.

For the record, the working directory it was using for my relative paths was two levels up from where I thought it was (i.e. the directory I was looking for all along)